# Put rows in columns and their corresponding values in rows in r

Tags: r, data.table

My original dataframe is in this format:

[image]

I want to take date in columns and variable `Sun` and `Soil_moisture` in rows and name it `metric`. Their values should be placed horizontally as shown below.

[image]

Is it doable in r?
Since r doesn't allow numbers to be in columns header I have prefixed with d

My sample dataset:

```
data <- data.frame(country = c("US","US","US","IND","IND","IND"),
                   state = c("TX","TX","TX","AP","AP","AP"),
                   date = c("20220601","20220602","20220603","20220601","20220602","20220603"),
                   Sun = c(30,35,40,20,30,40),
                   Soil_moisture = c(2.5,3.4,4.5,5.6,6.7,7.8))
```

I tried the `dcast` function but variable `Sun` is not coming into rows.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(data,country+state~date,value.var = "Sun")
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of `melt` and `dcast`:

```
library(data.table)

dcast(
  melt(
    setDT(data),
    id.vars = c("country", "state", "date"),
    variable.name = "metric"
  ),
  country + state + metric ~ paste0("d_", date)
)
```

**Output**

```
   country  state        metric d_20220601 d_20220602 d_20220603
    <char> <char>        <fctr>      <num>      <num>      <num>
1:     IND     AP           Sun       20.0       30.0       40.0
2:     IND     AP Soil_moisture        5.6        6.7        7.8
3:      US     TX           Sun       30.0       35.0       40.0
4:      US     TX Soil_moisture        2.5        3.4        4.5
```

If you left out `paste0`, then it would return just the date as the column name. But as @jdobres, this is generally not advisable.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly straightforward to do with **tidyverse** and its `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer` functions:

```
library(tidyverse)

new_data <- data %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(Sun, Soil_moisture), names_to = 'metric', values_to = 'value') %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_prefix = 'd_', names_from = 'date', values_from = 'value')

  country state metric        d_20220601 d_20220602 d_20220603
  <chr>   <chr> <chr>              <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 US      TX    Sun                 30         35         40  
2 US      TX    Soil_moisture        2.5        3.4        4.5
3 IND     AP    Sun                 20         30         40  
4 IND     AP    Soil_moisture        5.6        6.7        7.8
```

You could actually force `pivot_wider` to use the dates as column names by omitting the `names_prefix` argument, but it is generally a bad idea to have numeric column names.